# Dynamics CRM: how to add user if you cannot login as administrator

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

long story short, employee left the company who was the only administrator to the beginning stages of microsoft dynamics crm 2011. we have one user that can log in but he does not have administrator rights. we need to be able to create a new, administrator account so we can begin to customize microsoft dynamics crm. how can i do this without interacting with the dynamics crm interface?

Comment: You use on premise or online version? What type of authorization is used?

Comment: oh i forgot to mention that. it is on premise and we use windows AD authentication.

Comment: Do you have access with other administrative account to your AD?

Comment: yes - i have tried resetting the user account to the employee that left and then logging in as him but it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried to restart server after password reset? Also, try to update all services on machine that CRM or SQL server runs as this user. After that check in IIS CRMAppPool and update identity. That must help you with issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on-premise and still have sysadmin privileges on the SQL instance you can do this via SQL. If not, you'll need to work on getting privileges to SQL.

Once you are good in SQL you can add the System Administrator role to user that currently has access. Have them login and create new Users giving them System Administrator (as appropriate.) You are now back in business.

```
SELECT SystemUserId, FullName FROM SystemUser

SELECT RoleId, Name FROM [Role] WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'

INSERT INTO SystemUserRoles (SystemUserId, RoleId) VALUES ('User Id for the correct user in first query', 'Role Id from the second query')
```

Comment: that is what i was looking for. i do have sql access and was fumbling through the queries blind. will try this first thing in the AM.

Comment: how would i inject my username and password?

Comment: You don't. The username and password are in AD. You need to use an existing active CRM user (which you said you had) and use this script to assign them the System Administrator role. They would then access CRM and be able to add users and give those users the System Administrator role.